# LVM, LV Disk Replacement using Backup up Disk Image

Tags: linux, lvm

So, I recently inherited a Server that runs multiple LV (Logical Volumes) in a LVM Storage Pool that its disks are being used by Virsh KVM.

The issue is one of the Disks have recently corrupted and since then I have been using a backup image to be hosted but I want to get that image returned into the LVM storage pool and rehost as it originally was as there are automated backups running.

I want to find a way to get the raw file that was outputted back as the existing LV. But cannot figure out how to do it.

I have attached pictures of the LV storage and the Image I'm hoping to turn back into a LV disk but I'm not sure how to go about it.

[image: LV info]

[image: Drive Mapper Info]

[image: Raw Image to Replace LV Disk]

Comment: Please just copy & paste the text from the terminal directly to the post whenever possible (using code formatting) instead of posting pictures of text. You should also run the `lvs` command and post its output: it might be relevant as some of these LVs seem to be snapshots or copy-on-write duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "one of the Disks have recently corrupted", do you mean the VM's virtual disk, or the physical disk hosting the LV? If a physical disk has become corrupted, it will probably be unreliable for further use and should probably be replaced - has this been done?. If you want to do that, see below.

By the size of the file, your `/backup/rdnsrv2` seems to be a complete image of the entire LV.

To write it back onto the actual LV, you could do:

```
dd if=/backup/rdnsrv2 of=/dev/VG-sda/rdnsrv2 bs=1024k
```

or even:

```
cat /backup/rdnsrv2 > /dev/VG-sda/rdnsrv2
```

---

The naming of the VG suggests it is associated with the `/dev/sda` physical disk. This is an unnecessary limitation - a VG and even a LV within it can span multiple physical disks. You can even move LVM data from one disk to another while the LVs are in use. For example, if you wanted to replace your current `/dev/sda` with another disk (let's say it is `/dev/sdX`), you could do this:

- First, partition the new `/dev/sdX` to match `sda`. Since it's apparently the current boot disk for the host system, you'll need to create three partitions.
- Initialize the boot filesystems and copy the contents - you can do this because `/boot/efi` and `/boot` are only used while the system is actually booting, or while installing kernel/bootloader updates. On a non-boot disk, you could skip this.

```
    mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdX1
    mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt
    cp -a /boot/efi/* /mnt/
    umount /mnt
    umount /boot/efi
    mkfs.<appropriate type> /dev/sdX2
    mount /dev/sdX2 /mnt
    cp -a /boot/* /mnt/
    umount /mnt
    umount /boot
    lsblk -o +uuid /dev/sdX # note the UUIDs of sdX1 and sdX2
    <exit /etc/fstab to update the UUIDs of /boot/efi and /boot>
    systemctl daemon-reload
    mount /boot
    mount /boot/efi
    <verify that sdX1 is now at /boot/efi and sdX2 at /boot>
    grub-install /dev/sdX # ensures GRUB is up to date and EFI boot variable points to the correct disk
```

- Migrate the LVM data (even if the LVs are in use):

```
    pvcreate /dev/sdX3 
    vgextend VG-sda /dev/sdX3
    pvmove /dev/sda3
```

This `pvmove /dev/sda3` will migrate all LVM data out of `/dev/sda3` and onto different PVs in the same VG (= onto `/dev/sdX3` since there are no other alternatives). If it cannot move everything, it moves whatever it can and then stops.

- Tear down and remove `/dev/sda`:

```
    vgreduce VG-sda /dev/sda3 
    # this will harmlessly fail if there is still LV data on sda3

    lsblk /dev/sda   
    # verify no mounted filesystems and no LVs in use

    echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/delete   
    # /dev/sda* device nodes will vanish!
    # /dev/sda is now ready for hot-unplugging
```

Comment: Yes the corruption happened inside the LVs Virtual Disk specifically the one presented.

Comment: The /backup/rdnsrv2 is indeed a virtbackup image taken from the LV before it corrupted so yes i want to put it back into the Pool. 

Ill give it a go and let you know :) thanks so much

Comment: Thankyou so much for the insightful answer it is much appreciated and fixed my problem